# Is it ok to handle entire Authentication and Authorization using a Single cookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am used to authentication and authorization using a single cookie which has a user id in it. on each page I would check if the user exists with this user id or not. 
Is it safe to handle entire User Authentication and Authorization using a single cookie value stored on client side?
I want answers based on security issues related to my approach.
Will my website be easily hacked using creating fake cookies ??

Answer (score 0):

> Will my website be easily hacked using creating fake cookies ??

The answer is yes.

### How

A malicious user creates a dummy account in your system. Then alter the cookie value (which is User ID) using a tool like **Edit This Cookie** in chrome browser.

[image]

If User ID is Guid, it is a little bit hard to guess. However, it is a disaster waiting to happen.

### How to prevent it

Since you are using ASP.Net, the easiest one will be [ASP.Net Form Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). Here is an example,

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        "userName",
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // value of time out property
        false, // Value of IsPersistent property
        String.Empty,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

If you have a question regarding Form Authentication, please search in Google and StackOverFlow.